# Recovery Mode on tablet with no volume buttons?

Tags: rooting, adb, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, rom

- I have a Yarvik TAB10-201. The default launcher is corrupted.

  - I can get the tablet onto the recovery screen (Dead Android with red
    exclamation mark).
  - I can't bring up the options menu without volume up and down keys.
  - I can see the device in Android Multi Tool, but when doing wipe data, it just restarts back into recovery mode.
  - Rockchip does not detect the device for rooting as I can't hold volume up on boot.
  - I can see the device running ADB devices (shows as recovery status).
  - ADB reboot bootloader just turns the device off.
  - fastboot devices returns no devices.
  - I have the default ROM for the Yarvik tablet, but unsure how to flash if fastboot is not locating the device.

What other options do I have to recover? I am happy to root or recover.
I can't access the OS at all, on boot it just throws errors regarding the launcher.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53916/discussion-between-esqmo-and-ash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to esQmo for helping me look for a solution.

Turns out it was a Windows 8 problem, I switched to a different PC using Windows 7 and had no problems with RKBatchTool. For some reason even with correct drivers installed that worked when the tablet was plugged in, when the tablet was in Flash Mode Windows 8 had problems with the USB drivers.

For anyone that comes across this question.

I got the stock Firmware for Yarvik TAB10-201 from [here](http://www.rockchipfirmware.com/node/269).

I used RKBatchTool 1.7 and the RKB Driver Assistant for the drivers.

Comment: You can also use an OTG Keyboard... I had similar problems with my rockchip tablet